# Geometry algebraic Word Problem

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, area, word-problem

I am struggling on this question where I don't understand how to work out the area of the red square in the question. I have shown my workings in my question and is it possible if I could be assisted with this question and tell me where I went wrong.

Thank You

[image]

Comment: As long as the four vertices are inside the bigger square, the red square has area $100 cm^2$ always (for any rotational, translational position).

Comment: @Narasimham:  I think you may be making the same mistake that OP made.  If the outer square's edges are bisected by the internal line segments, surely the side of the inner square is less than 10cm.  The inner square sides are tilted with respect to the outer square sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, the large square can be decomposed into $20$ equal triangles, each one of area $20$. The central square contains four of them, hence its area is $80$.

[image]

Comment: wow thank you for the visual method

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  The side of the red square is not $10$.  The top side of the square is divided evenly, so each half is $10$.  The side of the red square is longer than $10$.  What is the length of the diagonal lines?  Pythagoras can help there.  Now draw a line from the midpoint of the top parallel to the diagonal line that is the top side of the red square.  You get a similar triangle.

After that, you had no reason to subtract $100$ from $400$.  If the side of the red square had been  $10$ the answer would be $100$.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean draw a line from the midpoint of the top parallel

Comment: oh nvm i see the triangles

Comment: i dont understand how I could use pythagoras to answer the question.

Comment: You want the length of the diagonal line.  You have a right triangle with one side of the square and one half side of the square.

Comment: oh right I understand it know

Answer (score 0):

The large square is made up of five of the red square, since each quadrilateral and small right triangle make one red square and there are four of these pairs within the large square. So the area of the red square is one-fifth of $400$, or $80$. You can check this. Since $20^2+10^2=500$, the long line within the big square is $$\sqrt 500\approx 22.36=2\times \sqrt 80+\sqrt 20\approx 2\times 8.94+4.47$$